# error: boost.fusion::for_each() and struct derived from boost.tuple

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion, boost-tuples

on compilation this code:

```
struct any_type: boost::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> {
   ...
};

struct functor {
   void operator()(const std::string& v) {
      std::cout << v << std::endl;
   }
};

int main() {
   any_type type;
   boost::fusion::for_each(type, functor());
}
```

get error: no type named 'category' in 'struct any_type'
why?
I want it to inherit from boost.tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from `boost::fusion::tuple` instead of `boost::tuple`.
**Note:** Consider making `void operator()(const std::string& v)` const